# Adding Time Range to a Single Date in a Parameter - SQL Report Builder/SSRS

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, sqlparameter, datetimerangefield

I'm working on building a couple reports for our company in SSRS in which we are looking to setup a date range between two dates with either a fixed time range set to the single date or to be able to define the time range for the single date. Does anyone know if this is possible at all and/or how it can be setup if it is?

We currently have a date range setup where we can append a time to it (i.e. 11/11/19 8:00:00 AM to 11/15/19 5:00:00 PM), but we are looking to be able to define the time range on the single date, i.e.:

Results between:

11/11/19 8:00:00 AM to 5:00:00 PM

to

11/15/19 8:00:00 AM to 5:00:00 PM

To give a visual representation:

[Date/Time Parameter idea screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzlQi.png)

I feel like this isn't a terribly far fetched idea but all I've been able to find online is singular date/time ranges but not the ability to define a time-range to a single date. Unless this can be achieved via a filter that would potentially work as the time range in our scenario could be fixed, but would be a catalyst to be able to define the time range as well.

Any help or links, ideas, guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could just set up the report to have 4 parameters - 1) `StartDate`, 2) `EndDate`, 3) `TimeRangeStart`, 4) `TimeRangeEnd`.  This way, you can tweak your query to fetch the correct data from the correct time range on each day.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm looking to accomplish but I do not know how to setup a time-range parameter. The parameter selection would look something like:

Start Date: <Calendar date select>
Time Range Start: <i.e. 8am to 5pm>

End Date: <calendar date select>
Time Range End: <i.e. 8am to 5pm>

The Time Range Start parameter would be bound to the Start Date and the Time Range End parameter would be bound to the End date.

Comment: Anybody have any ideas on how to accomplish this?